# Java Annotations: how to add to default array?

Tags: java, arrays, annotations

I'd like to create a custom annotation that defines some default values in an array and where usages of that annotation are able to add values to that array without re-specifying them.

So, annotation definition:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String[] value() default { "A", "B" };
}
```

Then the usage:

```
@MyAnnotation({"C", "D"})
public class MyClass { }
```

I'd like the runtime value on the annotation to be `{"A","B","C","D"}` - is there a way to do this? Again - I'd like it to be *without* re-specifying.

Consider having a large number of usages of `@MyAnnotation` and wanting to add `"X"` to the array value for each, without having to change each usages of `@MyAnnotation` - ie, changing just the `@MyAnnotation` to look like this:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String[] value() default { "A", "B", "X" };
}
```

Comment: Also, if this can be solved using Spring and `@AliasFor`, I'm happy to see that as well.

Comment: How are you processing the annotated types?

Comment: You could maybe do it in the code that uses MyAnnotation, but I'd be shocked if there was a better alternative short of bytecode rewriting.

Comment: If it's a custom annotation, with probably custom handling via Reflection, then what about separating 2 annotation fields: kind of "basicValues" and "additionalValues" and specify only the latter in user code? Concat both arrays while annotation processing.

Comment: @Unmitigated I'm not processing it - in my actual use case, `@MyAnnotation` is a composition annotation composing a number of Spring annotations - so it is Spring that is processing the annotation.